# Computing average values over sections of date/time

Tags: mysql, datetime, select, timespan

**Problem:**

I have a database of sensor readings with a timestamp for the time the sensor was read. Basically it looks like this:

```
Sensor | Timestamp | Value
```

Now I want to make a graph out of this data and I want to make several different graphs. Say I want one for the last day, one for the last week and one for the last month. The resolution of each graph will be different so for the day-graph the resolution would be 1 minute. For the week graph it would be one hour and for the month graph it would be one day, or quarter of a day.

So I would like an output that is the average of each resolution (eg. Day = Average over the minute, Week = Average over the hour and so on)

Ex:

```
Sensor | Start | End | Average
```

How do I do this easily and quickly in mySQL? I suspect it invoves creating a temporary table or sorts and joining the sensor data with that to get the average values of the sensor? But my knowledge of mySQL is limited at best.

Is there a really clever way to do this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
SELECT  DAY(Timestamp), HOUR(Timestamp), MINUTE(Timestamp), AVG(value)
FROM    mytable
GROUP BY
        DAY(Timestamp), HOUR(Timestamp), MINUTE(Timestamp) WITH ROLLUP
```

`WITH ROLLUP` clause here produces extra rows with averages for each `HOUR` and `DAY`, like this:

```
SELECT  DAY(ts), HOUR(ts), MINUTE(ts), COUNT(*)
FROM    (
        SELECT  CAST('2009-06-02 20:00:00' AS DATETIME) AS ts
        UNION ALL
        SELECT  CAST('2009-06-02 20:30:00' AS DATETIME) AS ts
        UNION ALL
        SELECT  CAST('2009-06-02 21:30:00' AS DATETIME) AS ts
        UNION ALL
        SELECT  CAST('2009-06-03 21:30:00' AS DATETIME) AS ts
        ) q
GROUP BY
        DAY(ts), HOUR(ts), MINUTE(ts) WITH ROLLUP
```

```
2, 20, 0, 1
2, 20, 30, 1
2, 20, NULL, 2
2, 21, 30, 1
2, 21, NULL, 1
2, NULL, NULL, 3
3, 21, 30, 1
3, 21, NULL, 1
3, NULL, NULL, 1
NULL, NULL, NULL, 4
```

`2, 20, NULL, 2` here means that `COUNT(*)` is `2` for `DAY = 2`, `HOUR = 20` and all minutes.

Comment: This produces something that is close to the results I'm expecting.
What does the "WITH ROLLUP" do because it seems it produces the same results if I remove it?

Comment: From MySQL Reference Manual:  
"Adding a WITH ROLLUP modifier to the GROUP BY clause causes the query to produce another row that shows the grand total over all values"

Comment: I'm guessing I could use whatever date function to do the grouping just so that it'll be easier to do the different graphs so this is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Not quite the result table you wanted, but here's a starter for doing a 1 minute resolution:

```
SELECT sensor,minute(timestamp),avg(value) 
FROM table 
WHERE <time period specifier limits to a single hour>
GROUP BY sensor, minute(timestamp)
```

Answer (score 2):

I've used code very similar to this (untested, but it's taking from working code)

set the variables:

```
$seconds = 3600;
$start = mktime(...);  // say 2 hrs ago
$end   = .... // 1 hour after $start
```

then run the query

```
SELECT MAX(`when`) AS top_When, MIN(`when`) AS low_When,
   ROUND(AVG(sensor)) AS Avg_S,
   (MAX(`when`) - MIN(`when`)) AS dur, /* the duration in seconds of the actual period */
   ((floor(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(`when`) / $seconds)) * $seconds) as Epoch
   FROM `sensor_stats`
   WHERE `when` >= '$start' AND `when` <= '$end' and duration=30
   GROUP BY Epoch/*((floor(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(`when`) / $seconds)) * $seconds)*/
```

The advantage of this is that you can have whatever time periods you want - and not even required to have them on 'round numbers', like a complete clock-hour (even a clock-minute, 0-59).

Comment: I can't get this query to work: "Unknown column 'duration' in 'where clause'". Does not work if I replace duration with dur either.

Comment: In my original database, I store how long a period that data is for (maybe 30 seconds, maybe an hour, maybe a day). You can probably drop that part of the query (' and duration=30') since your own table is a point-in-time record.