# How to select the average of my "Value" column over an hour using the "Timestamp" column in my table

Tags: mysql, grafana

My table is called bluescope_data

I have three columns in this table, including “Timestamp”, “Value”, “lastchanged” as illustrated in the image below. The data is being displayed on a connecting dashboard. I want to only display the average of the “Value” column over each hour as depicted in the image below.

[image: Table Layout]

Could someone please help me modify my code below so that the average “Value” over each hour of the Timestamp is outputted.

```
    SELECT
  Timestamp AS "time",
  Value
FROM bluescopegasdata
ORDER BY Timestamp desc
```

Comment: See similar question in the link:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/940550/computing-average-values-over-sections-of-date-time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are already macros that help with grouping by time interval:

```
    SELECT $__timeGroup(Timestamp, '1h'),
        avg(Value)
    FROM bluescopegas_data
    WHERE $__timeFilter(Timestamp)
    GROUP BY 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the Time period as you required. It will output avg value for each hour

```
 SELECT DATE(Timestamp), hour(Timestamp),avg(Value) 
    FROM bluescopegasdata
    WHERE Timestamp between '2021-04-29 01:00:00' and '2021-04-29 12:00:00'
    GROUP BY hour(Timestamp)
```